# Swift Reloaddata does not call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview and I am trying to download file from my server. When user open tableview page first time and download file everything working correctly. I can show progress bar value in tableview cell. Delegate function I am updating progress value and then calling tableView.reloadData(). In first time everything working.

But when I comeback to previous page, open tableview again then click download button I can not update tableview. tableView.reloadData() calls numberOfRowsInSection with correct data count. but not call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Also I tried with following code and it dod not work too

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When I use following code it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath function but now update my values. (When I print the cell value it shows correct value but now shown on screen)

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.clickSongRowIndex[cellNum], section: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

Comment: Do you keep data in NSFetchResultController ?

Comment: No. I am getting data from my server and put it in array.

Comment: When you open the table view again, are you sure its visible and does not get hidden by improper constraints

Comment: Yes it is visible, I can see the correct data and when I select the row download starts. Just I can not update the row text. But when I scroll the tableview and come back to row it is updated.